# Update local commit message after updating commit message on Gerrit UI?

Tags: git, github, gerrit

I have updated commit message in gerrit UI directly there but this is not changed in my local commit in my laptop. How can I update my local commit message or How can I pull my updated gerrit changes to my local so that if I need to update more code onto it in the same branch so I can do it.

I tried to "git pull" or "git fetch" but didn't work for me.
Have also tried with cherry-pick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the download path command in your change, it will allow you to copy the command to your command/bash prompt, see the example from [gerrit](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/c/gerrit/+/391215).

[image]